# How do I go around binding this script to an anchor's click event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm having trouble implementing a tracking pixel script, specifically with binding the script to a click event.

Here's the JavaScript I got from the pixel tracking service provider:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">    
            var __autoFirePixels = true;    
            (function() {
                    var script = document.createElement('script');
                    script.type = 'text/javascript';
                    script.setAttribute('async', 'true');
                    script.src = document.location.protocol+
                                '//pixel.traffiliate.com/pixel/pixels.js.php'+
                                'allsortsofapiinformation';
                    document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script);
        })();
</script>
```

I need this code to be triggered when a click-to-call button has been clicked - there are two buttons like this in the landing page.

I'm feeling the solution is right around the corner, I'd appreciate any help in finding a solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a href="#" id="click-to-call">Click to call</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
var trackPixel = function() {
  var __autoFirePixels = true;
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.setAttribute('async', 'true');
  script.src = document.location.protocol+
  '//pixel.traffiliate.com/pixel/pixels.js.php'+
  'allsortsofapiinformation';
  document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script);
}
document.getElementById('click-to-call').onclick = trackPixel;
document.getElementById('click-to-call2').onclick = trackPixel;
document.getElementById('click-to-call3').onclick = trackPixel;
</script>
```

Comment: Nice! thanks! i have 2 buttons that are supposed to trigger this, how do i go around triggering the script if i have 2 different buttons with 2 differnt IDs?